# el.text is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having some trouble with this stubborn script, for some reason it wont acknowledge `currentEl.text()` as a function in script form. However if i type it into the console it works...

```
window.onload = function() {
  function truncTitle(currentEl) {
    currentElText = currentEl.text();
    if (currentElText.split(" ").length <= 16) {
      newText = jQuery.trim(currentElText).substring(0, 6).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "...";
      currentEl.text(newText);
    }
  };
  currentEl = jQuery('.post-slider-oc .wp-post-title a');
  currentEl.each(truncTitle);
}
```

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: within the each statement, the truncTitle function runs fine, but then fails on

    currentElText = currentEl.text();

Comment: Ooh yes.. Felix read you correctly..Refer the answer..

Comment: Always [**read the documentation**](https://api.jquery.com/each/) before you use an unfamiliar method! Everything you needed to know to solve this issue was in there.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument passed to the `.each` callback is the **index** of the element in the collection. Either use `this` or use a second argument:

```
function truncTitle(index, currentEl) {
  // ...
}
```

Note that you will also have to pass `this` or `currentEl` to jQuery (`$(this)`, `$(currentEl)`), since they will both be plain DOM elements, not jQuery objects.

See the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

> function
>      Type: Function( Integer index, Element element )
>      A function to execute for each matched element.
>
> ```
> $( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
>   console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
> });
> ```

Comment: Note, `.each()` is not necessary to achieve expected result. `.text(function(index, text){})` should iterate all elements of original selector

Comment: i tried this, but no luck?

`function truncTitle(index, currentEl) {
      currentElText = jQuery(this).text();
            if (isMobile() == !false && currentElText.split(" ").length <= 16) {
                newText = jQuery.trim(currentElText).substring(0, 6).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "...";
                currentEl.text(newText);
        }
    };

    currentEl = jQuery('.post-slider-oc .wp-post-title a');
    currentEl.each(truncTitle(index));
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        currentEl.each(truncTitle(this));
    });
}`

Comment: @Silicabello: Why are you suddenly doing `currentEl.each(truncTitle(index));`? That is wrong.

Comment: I dont think im quite grasping the syntax :( i got it from this 
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {

Comment: @Silicabello: `truncTitle(index)` **calls** the function and passes the variable `index` to it. `function( index ) {...}` **defines** a function that takes a single argument. `$( "li" ).each(function( index ) { ... })` simply means that the function is defined "inline" and directly passed to `.each`. You on the other hand are defining the function "outside" (`function truncTitle(index, currentEl) {...}`) and pass it later (`.each(truncTitle)`). Both ways are perfectly fine.

Comment: ahh of course, when you stare at code for so long you make easy things complicated, thanks!

Comment: So, I think what @FelixKling is saying is `jQuery(window).load(function(){
 jQuery('.post-slider-oc .wp-post-title a').each(function(i) {
  var currentEl = jQuery(this);
  var currentElText = currentEl.text();
     if (currentElText.split(" ").length <= 16) {
       var newText = jQuery.trim(currentElText).substring(0, 6).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "...";
       currentEl.text(newText);
     }
 });
});`

Answer (score 2):

`.each()` is not necessary to achieve expected result, you can use [`.text(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)

```
  function truncTitle(index, currentElText) {
    if (currentElText.split(" ").length <= 16) {
      newText = jQuery.trim(currentElText).substring(0, 6)
                .split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "...";
      return newText
    } else {
        return currentElText
    }
  };
  currentEl = jQuery('.post-slider-oc .wp-post-title a');
  currentEl.text(truncTitle);
```

Comment: This is most likely even more correct, since `currentEl.text(newText);` would otherwise set the content of each element to the same value.